# Automatically re-size one div to another div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs side by side.

The left div has all different heights, how can I make the right div automatically resize to the size of left div? If the content of the right div is larger than the left div there should be a scroll bar added to it.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"><!-- PHP Generated Content --></div>
    <div class="right"><!-- PHP Generated Content --></div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.left{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
.right{
    width: 29%;
    float: right;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper{
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/MJrS9/

Comment: Why can't you set `height: 100%` for both divs?

Comment: Don't get it, where do you specify left div's size? Or it's determined by it's content? Why does right div have height 100%? Should the wrapper be as tall as left div? A www.jsfiddle.net would help.

Comment: The left div's height is determined by it's content. The wrapper should be re-sized based on the left div's size.

Comment: Yaarrggh. Floats are for text contexts, not block display. Yaarrggh.

Comment: @IlanBiala - http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/MJrS9/

Answer (score 0):

Easy equal height columns:

```
.left{
    width: 70%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right{
    width: 29%;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    display: table-cell;
}
.wrapper{
    display: table;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g5mvs/

Comment: My current preferred method, if you don't need IE7 support. Or I suppose you'll have to shim it for it.

Comment: I didn't mention in my original, that the right div shouldn't be taller than the left div. If it is, auto scroll

Comment: I'm almost positive the addition of the scrollbar on the right side when there's short content on the left puts this outside the realm of what's possible with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving a pre-defined height to the parent '.wrapper', there is no way (that I can see) of detecting the height set against '.left' and applying it to '.right'. Even setting the height of the right div to 'inherit' would only pick up the height which is adjusting dynamically anyway. Perhaps someone could suggest a solution using javascript.